# JQuery program doesn't do what I expect

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why when I click to remove items, it's not removing the element I clicked, but it's removing from the last added to the first one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your second function and see what `this` refers to.

Comment: could probably be because on HTML you're putting `class` instead of `id` or viceversa. For more help provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue also do it in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: provide `HTML` part too

Comment: Code behaves as it should, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/9DLbz/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much Dhaval Marthak, it really works!!

Comment: Well, thanks for having said it works, we were puzzled. Now it seems you can delete your question...